# Selenium click on XPath button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have the following code when I inspect on Chrome.

```
<span id="button-1111-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on" style="">New Email</span>
```

I need to click on the label "New Email", but how should invoke it in Selenium (I'm using Python).

```
def CreateMail():
    EmailButton="//*[contains(text(),'New Email')]"
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath(EmailButton)  // there is no method to enable click.
```

Comment: Did you try the method `.click()` like `driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()`

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath(EmailButton).click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: You probably want to click it's parent container. not every element is clickable. But without seeing it, i can't help.

Comment: when i click it, i see the above code in my chrome console (inspect element)

Comment: Probably, the clickable element is its parent, i don't see the parent in here.

Comment: @TharangaAbeyseela, you should use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(EmailButton)[0]` or `driver.find_element_by_xpath(EmailButton)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_id("button-1111-btnInnerEl").click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

Comment: Based on the html it should work. Probably you need to take another action to make it interactable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `execute_script`

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('button-1111-btnInnerEl').click()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement : "driver.find_**elements**_by_xpath(EmailButton)" . Click does not work on group of elements. It is actionable only on single element. So you use a singular finder.

```
driver.find_**element**_by_id(EmailButton).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This XPath will work for you.If you want to validate xpath using your chrome browser just paste this text on your chrome console `$x("//*[text()='New Email']")` and check how many elements found using this XPath

```
 driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='New Email']")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared, the `id` attribute looks dynamic to me. So we must construct a dynamic `xpath` or `css`. Additionally instead of `find_elements` we have to use `find_element` so a single `WebElement` is returned and we can invoke the `click()` method. Finally, if you look at the node properly, the unselectable attribute is on so we will take help of `JavascriptExecutor` as follows :

```
myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'button-')][@class='x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", myElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. Finally i found the answer to my question.I had to add a wait statement, before finding the key. key wasn't present when the page loads, so had to wait a little bit to find the correct key.

```
def CreateMail():
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "button-1143-btnInnerEl")))
    driver.find_element_by_id("button-1143-btnInnerEl").click()

except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is different way for locating elements
but in your case there is a ID,
so you can prefer id if its exists

find solution below :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("button-1111-btnInnerEl").click()
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47503601/501011)

Comment: Exact duplicate